# What qualifications does a registered Copyright Agent need?

Tags: copyright

I'm considering appointing somebody to be a registered Copyright Agent with the US government. What qualifications do they need? Do they need to be a lawyer or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, anybody can be a registered copyright agent, even you! You just have to have an easy way to reach you, including email and phone, and enough time to actually respond to take-down requests expeditiously.

Just make sure to make up your mind once and for all before submitting the request, because editing a registration costs as much as a new registration.